# How to upgrade chromedriver version for appium?

Tags: appium

I am getting the following error when attempting to run an Appium script on the Chrome Version 65:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.109)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.4 x86_64)

I have found that the chromedriver version needs to be updated but I can't find a way to successfully do this.

So my question is how do I upgrade the chromedriver version to the latest version?

Answer (score 2):

So first, with *each update to Chromedriver there is an increase in the minimum supported version of Chrome* => older devices are often unable to be automated with the bundled version.

So its not **appium/chromdriver** compatibility, its your **device browser/ chromdriver versions** compatibility check.

To check versions compatibility you go look [here](https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/)

When you figure out whats version works for you, run:

```
npm install appium --chromedriver_version="2.37"
```

This version supports Chrome v 64-66

Comment: I did it, even I restarted the machine after installing. But still I'm facing the same problem. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

The subjected issue can be resolved (In my case this works) if we pass the additional argument while starting the appium server in the local system.

CLI Command: `appium --allow-insecure chromedriver_autodownload`

The script will automatically search for the newest chromedriver version that supports the given browser/web view, download it (the hash sum is verified as well for the downloaded archive) and add to the chromedriverChromeMappingFile mapping.

For more details please refer to the official documentation of appium: [Compatible chromedriver issue fixes options](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver/)

Hope this helps!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the latest chromedriver from here :
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Upgrade your appium server, appium java client to latest version.